# Is there a proc to generate a "missing at random" situation in SAS?

Tags: sas, missing-data

Just curious to know if there is a proc or a function that can automatically generate MAR situation in SAS.

Comment: I have rolled back to Nick Stauner's edit because of [this meta post](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1305/please-do-not-migrate-low-quality-questions), which clearly asks posts that are on topic elsewhere are improved *here* first, *then moved*. I attempted to reject the previous rollback but by the time I located the correct post to point to, it had already been approved.

Comment: You can delete random data in the DATA step in SAS using any of random number functions or calls, or through other methods if you have a variable that can serve (something like an ID number that is randomly assigned).

Comment: Thanks Peter, i am working logic that is very similar to your suggestion.

Comment: @PeterFlom I encourage you to post an answer. :)