# how to generate Missing at Random data in SAS?

Tags: sas, missing-data

I am wondering how to generate Missing at random dataset in SAS. I have two variables X and Y both with normal distribution and I want to generate Missing values in Y depending on X (with MAR mechanism) ?

Comment: You might see the suggestions on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025939/is-there-a-proc-to-generate-a-missing-at-random-situation-in-sas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link which I found helpful to generate MAR data

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/paperexamples/schafer1/

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look to PROC MI:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mi_sect001.htm

Comment: This isn't sufficiently detailed to be a good answer.  I'm also not sure it's right, as I at least don't see how to use MI to *generate* MCAR data - only to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks Joe you are right Proc MI only generate monotone pattern missing values but not the mechanism.